# SuiteScript2.0 - Including a custom file

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Im working with **suitescript 2.0** (netsuite) and Im wondering how would I go about including a custom class (object) using it's new API. For example I'm trying to include a controller class but getting a "module not found" warning. See snippet below

```
/**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType Restlet
     */
    define(['N/record', 'N/error', "src/My_Controller"],
        function (record, error, My_Controller) {
            var controller = new My_Controller();
            ...
```

The error message is: `Module does not exist: src/My_Controller.js` when in fact it is there. Is this the correct way to do it?

The NetSuite help center has nothing about inclusion of custom/ancillary javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference custom modules by their path in the File Cabinet. This can be either relative to the current file or relative to the root of the File Cabinet. So it will look something like:

```
define(['N/record', 'N/error', '/SuiteScripts/my-project/src/My_Controller'], ...)
```

or:

```
define(['N/record', 'N/error', './src/My_Controller'], ...)
```

Assuming that `src` is in the same directory as this file.

Comment: This got me one step further but still getting this error: TypeError: My_Controller is not a function. Ill check my exports but thanks alot

Comment: You need to define your custom file as an AMD module using the `define` function. Your module will need to export a `construct` function or whatever name you'd like to invoke, and then you will reference it in your Restlet as `My_Controller.construct()`